# Rails 5 - data validation gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app that I am building to learn RoR, I want to start learning more about validations. Besides building custom validations (e.g. using regex), I was wondering what the best gems are for commonly found validations for data like addresses, currencies, dates/time formatting, languages, etc.? This in order to build a basic set to use on new apps.

I came across these below to use:

- [Countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries)
- [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)
- [IBAN](https://github.com/alphasights/iban-tools) (international bank account)
- [Validate Timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness)
- [email validation](https://github.com/riscfuture/email_validation)

How about incoterms, unit of measure (from UNECE or ISO20022) or VAT id? Any other ones that I should look at?

Comment: the only other one i've used is validates_lengths_from_database.

Comment: just a comment from experience. don't rely on rails uniqueness validation on large apps with multiple connections. make sure your DB has the proper unique indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you dig deeper into validations you'll find that requiring gems built to handle certain themes (email/currency etc) aren't nearly as neat as just developing a custom validation for your specific use case.  For example, I wouldn't use anything but a regex on emails to verify there's an @ symbol and some characters after it because there are now so many suffixes (.co/.uk/.me/.us etc.) which in turn hardly warrants a prebuilt gem. Currency validation would also normally be simple since you'd expect a specific format of say #.## however if you deviate from that you'd be far better off doing another custom validator and not falling back to an outside library. Countries normally wouldn't be put through a validation that's country specific since you'll probably have them select a country from a preset list you've created and so the standard rails validations like `presence` would suffice.  With that said, a validation gem I like to use that handles client-side validations not specific to any theme is "clientSideValidations" gem however it's only for rails 4.2.